# Linear algorithm to find number of distinct closed curves in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, directed-graph

Is there any linear-time algorithm to find the number of distinct closed paths in a directed graph?

A pseudocode explanation would suffice.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't want to list them, I just want to find the number of closed paths....so maybe I guess...

Comment: You're quite right, reading comprehension failure on my part -- sorry!  I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, "cycle" always means "simple cycle" -- i.e., a sequence of vertices in which every adjacent pair of vertices are linked by an edge in the original graph G, the first and last vertex are equal, and every other vertex in the sequence apppears at most once.

After quite some looking, I found a proof that this problem is NP-hard -- so not only does no one know a way to solve it in linear time, no one knows a way to solve it in *polynomial* time.

The proof I found is on p. 2 of http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f11/lecture23.pdf, which was linked to from [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-count-the-number-of-cycles-in-a-directed-graph).

I'll paraphrase and expand on it a little bit (I didn't understand why they wrote "n^n" as "2^(n log n)") here:

Suppose we have a digraph G and we want to know if G contains a Hamiltonian Cycle.  We could solve this known-NP-hard problem in polynomial time if we had a polynomial time for your problem (counting the number of simple cycles in a directed graph) as follows:

Build a new graph G' from G by taking each edge (u, v) in G and replacing it with a "gadget" that creates n^n distinct paths from u to v.  This can be done as follows: for each edge (u, v) in G, make a n-by-n grid of n^2 fresh vertices in G', connecting u to each of the n vertices in the first row, each of these n vertices to each of the n vertices in the next row (for n^2 total first-row-to-second-row edges), each of the vertices in the second row to each of the vertices in the third row, and so on until the nth and final row.  Connect each vertex in the final row to v.  We can get from u to v in exactly n^n different ways via these vertices: on each of the n rows, we can choose any one of the n vertices in that row to be on a path from u to v.  Clearly this gadget has polynomial size (n^2 vertices and (n-1)n^2 + 2n edges), and we will need at most n^2 copies of it (one for each edge in G) so G' does too.  We will feed this constructed graph G' to any algorithm for counting directed cycles in a digraph, and use the answer to determine whether G has a Hamiltonian Cycle.

First, suppose G has a Hamiltonian Cycle.  Then that cycle, being Hamiltonian, has n edges, so it corresponds in G' to (n^n)^n different cycles, so there are at least this many cycles in G'.  (There will probably be more, corresponding to other cycles present in G, but that doesn't matter.)

OTOH, suppose G has no Hamiltonian Cycle.  Then the longest cycle that it can have has length n-1, and the maximum *number* of cycles that it can have is upper-bounded by n^(n-1).  To see that, notice that any cycle of length at most n-1 can be written as a sequence of n-1 numbers each in the range 1 to n, by finding the smallest-numbered vertex in the cycle, writing it down, and then writing down each successive vertex in the cycle until the original vertex is reached again, at which point we could (say) keep writing down the original vertex's number until we have written down n-1 numbers in total.  Every cycle produces a distinct vector of n-1 numbers, and there are at most n^(n-1) such vectors, so there can be at most n^(n-1) distinct cycles in G.  With upper bounds on the number and length of cycles in G, we can now calculate an upper bound on the number of cycles in G': since a single cycle in G can have at most n-1 edges, it can produce at most (n^n)^(n-1) cycles in G'; and since there can be at most n^(n-1) distinct cycles in G, there can be at most n^(n-1)*(n^n)^(n-1) cycles in G' overall.  But that simplifies to n^(n^2-n)*n^(n-1) and from there to n^(n^2-1), which is clearly strictly less than n^(n^2).

So we can tell whether G has a Hamiltonian Cycle by feeding G' to an algorithm for counting cycles in a digraph and looking at the answer: if it is at least n^(n^2) then G has a Hamiltonian Cycle, while if it is below n^(n^2) then G has no Hamiltonian Cycle.  Thus if there existed a polynomial-time algorithm for counting cycles in a digraph, we could also solve Hamiltonian Cycle (and all other NP-complete problems) in polynomial time.